# Why libprocessgroup will kill my app?

Tags: android

I have a strange issue on some Android 5.X devices such as HTC_m9u. When my app launches it will be shutdown immediately. I can't see any crash information in the `adb logcat` but get these messages instead:

```
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 732 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 732 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/libprocessgroup( 1107): Killing pid 731 in uid 10156 as part of process group 681
I/ActivityManager( 1107): Process com.my.app (pid 681) has died
```

Why the libprocessgroup kills my app? What would be a reason?